# Error: received 4002 (private use) Error while decoding payload.; then sent 4002 (private use) Error while decoding payload

Tags: python, websocket, discord

Hello how to fix this error "Error: received 4002 (private use) Error while decoding payload.; then sent 4002 (private use) Error while decoding payload." im using latest version of websockets but it still giving me this error can someone help me?

code:

```
        import asyncio
        import websockets
        import json
        from json import loads
        import easygui, os
        DISCORD_ACCESS_TOKEN = "yes"
        #AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "x.mp3"

        async def send_audio(websocket):
            with open(easygui.fileopenbox(), "rb") as audio_file:
                audio_data = audio_file.read()
                await websocket.send(audio_data)

        async def receive_audio(websocket):
            try:
                async for message in websocket:
                    print(message)
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")


        async def play_audio():
            async with websockets.connect("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=8&encoding=json") as websocket:
                auth_payload = {
                    "op": 2,
                    "d": {
                        "token": DISCORD_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                        "properties": {"$os": "windows","$browser": "Discord","$device": "desktop",
                        #"intents": 513,
                    },
                }
                }
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(auth_payload))
                voice_payload = {
                    "op": 4,
                    "d": {
                        "guild_id": "1092509925021864027",
                        "channel_id": "1092849943376580618",
                        "self_mute": False,
                        "self_deaf": False,
                    },
                }
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(voice_payload))
                
                gay_payload = {
                    "op": 18,
                    "d": {"type": "guild","guild_id": "1092509925021864027","channel_id": "1092849943376580618","preferred_region": "russia"}
                }
                
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(gay_payload))
                #websocket.send(json.dumps({"op": 1,"d": None}))
                await send_audio(websocket)

                await receive_audio(websocket)`
                asyncio.run(play_audio())
```

i was trying to update my imports and using other mp3 sounds